Question regarding kosher status
Genetic engineers create a pig that lives permanently under water (like a whale), has fins and scales. Is it kosher?
(To be clear: This is not about a genetically engineered pig that chews the cud, as referenced in an older question. This is about a genetically engineered pig which becomes a fish by Torah definition)

Pigs are explicitly listed as unclean animals. So as long as one would still consider it a pig, then I’m guessing no it wouldn’t be kosher  There are also prohibitions about wearing clothes of mixed clothe, or planting multiple types of seed in a field, etc. That may come into play with regards to genetically modified foods that would make in non-kosher even if it wasn’t to still be considered a pig  Just some considerations off the top of my head.
